# How to flip a crossbow so it looks like a bow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

im creating a map where the crossbow is a shotgun, i sucessfully flipped the weapon but in first person when loaded it looks like this: 
[image]
how can i fix this so it looks straight?
this is the changes i made to the models code of the crossbow texture only
rotation first and third person right hand is now : 0, -90, 55 
rotation first and thir person right hand before: -90 0 -55

also, if anyone know how i change the sound effects for the crossbow it would be really helpful